# How does mixing relaxed and acquire/release accesses on the same atomic variable affect synchronises-with?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a question about the definition of the synchronises-with relation in the C++ memory model when relaxed and acquire/release accesses are mixed on one and the same atomic variable. Consider the following example consisting of a global initialiser and three threads:

```
int x = 0;
std::atomic<int> atm(0);

[thread T1]
x = 42;
atm.store(1, std::memory_order_release);

[thread T2]
if (atm.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
    atm.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);

[thread T3]
int value = atm.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
assert(value != 1 || x == 42);  // Hopefully this is guaranteed to hold.
assert(value != 2 || x == 42);  // Does this assert hold necessarily??
```

My question is whether the second assert in `T3` can fail under the C++ memory model. Note that [the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786334/c11-c11-memory-model-acquire-release-relaxed-specifics) suggests that the assert could not fail if `T2` used load/acquire and store/release; please correct me if I got this wrong. However, as stated above, the answer seems to depend on how exactly the synchronises-with relation is defined in this case. I was confused by the text on cppreference, and I came up with the following two possible readings.

1. The second assert fails. The store to `atm` in `T1` could be conceptually understood as storing `1_release` where `_release` is annotation specifying how the value was stored; along the same lines, the store in `T2` could be understood as storing `2_relaxed`. Hence, if the load in `T3` returns  `2`, the thread actually read `2_relaxed`; thus, the load in `T3` **does not** synchronise-with the store in `T1` and there is no guarantee that `T3` sees `x == 42`. However, if the load in `T3` returns `1`, then `1_release` was read, and therefore the load in `T3` synchronises-with the store in `T1` and `T3` is guaranteed to see `x == 42`.
2. The second assert success. If the load in `T3` returns `2`, then this load reads a side-effect of the relaxed store in `T2`; however, this store of `T2` is present in the modification order of `atm` only if the modification order of `atm` contains a preceding store with a release semantics. Therefore, the load/acquire in `T3` synchronises-with the store/release of `T1` because the latter necessarily precedes the former in the modification order of `atm`.

At first glance, [the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382626/does-a-single-load-synchronize-with-multiple-stores?rq=1) seems to suggest that my reading 1 is correct. However, that answer seems to be different in a subtle way: all stores in the answer are release, and the crux of the question is to see that load/acquire and store/release establishes synchronises-with between a pair of threads. In contrast, my question is about how exactly synchronises-with is defined when memory orders are heterogeneous.

I actually hope that reading 2 is correct since this would make reasoning about concurrency easier. Thread `T2` does not read or write any memory other than `atm`; therefore, `T2` itself has no synchronisation requirements and should therefore be able to use relaxed memory order. In contrast, `T1` publishes `x` and `T3` consumes it -- that is, these two threads communicate with each other so they should clearly use acquire/release semantics. In other words, if interpretation 1 turns out to be correct, then the code `T2` cannot be written by thinking only about what `T2` does; rather, the code of `T2` needs to know that it should not "disturb" synchronisation between `T1` and `T3`.

In any case, knowing what exactly is sanctioned by the standard in this case seems absolutely crucial to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use relaxed ordering on a separate load & store in T2, the release sequence is broken and the second assert can trigger (although not on a TSO platform such as X86).
You can fix this by either using acq/rel ordering in thread T2 (as you suggested) or by modifying T2 to use an atomic read-modify-write operation (RMW), like this:

```
[Thread T2]
int ret;
do {
    int val = 1;
    ret = atm.compare_exchange_weak(val, 2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
} while (ret != 0);
```

The modification order of `atm` is 0-1-2 and T3 will pick up on either 1 or 2 and no assert can fail.

Another valid implementation of T2 is:

```
[thread T2]
if (atm.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
{
    atm.exchange(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Here the RMW itself is unconditional and it must be accompanied by an if-statement & (relaxed) load to ensure that the modification order of `atm` is 0-1 or 0-1-2
Without the if-statement, the modification order could be 0-2 which can cause the assert to fail.  (This works because we know there is only one other write in the whole rest of the program.  Separate `if()` / `exchange` is of course *not* in general equivalent to `compare_exchange_strong`.)

In the C++ standard, the following quotes are related:

> [intro.races]
> A release sequence headed by a release operation A on an atomic object M is a maximal contiguous subsequence
> of side effects in the modification order of M, where the first operation is A, and every subsequent
> operation is an atomic read-modify-write operation.

> [atomics.order]
> An atomic operation A that performs a release operation on an atomic object M synchronizes with an atomic
> operation B that performs an acquire operation on M and takes its value from any side effect in the release
> sequence headed by A.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694459/using-an-atomic-read-modify-write-operation-in-a-release-sequence) is about *why* an RMW works in a release sequence.

Comment: Thank you for a very quick and clear answer. So I see: relaxed compare_exhange_* is fine, but an ordinary store(x, relaxed) isn’t. I must admit that this is not really obvious, and reading the language of the standard isn’t easiest. In any case, this is really important to know!

Comment: Actually, could you please clarify one more thing: if T2 did a load(relaxed) but otherwise used relaxed compare_exchange_weak to modify the value, this wouldn’t interrupt the release sequence, would it? In other words, loads are irrelevant, and we only care about modifications, right?

Comment: And one more question: why do we then need compare_exhange_* with acquire/release? I mean, if compare_exhange_* never breaks the release sequence, we should always get the effects of acquire/release with just relaxed — or have I misunderstood something? (Of course, seq_cst would be a different matter.)

Comment: When you say forward: what if I didn’t use a while loop? Then I would just read it and perhaps do nothing with the value. The load itself isn’t breaking the sequence, right?

Comment: @Boris The RMW in the release sequence (compare_exchange_) does not require ordering (relaxed is fine). I asked a question about why it works this way (linked in the answer).

Comment: The while loop is necessary so that T2 forwards the correct value. T1: stores(rel) 1, T2: increments 1->2 (RMW, relaxed), T3: loads(acq) 2.. That is a correct release sequence. If T3 loads 1 (acq), the synchronization is between T1 & T3 and it does not matter what T2 does

Comment: Thank you. I still don’t quite understand the point of a while loop and the notion of “correct value”. Say `T2` did `if (atm.load(std::mo_relaxed) == 1) { int expected = 1; std::compare_exchange_weak(expected, 2, std::mo_relaxed); }` — that is, `T2` tries to CAS 2 when it sees 1, but gives up on failure. As far as I understand it, asserts in my example can’t fail. (1) If CAS succeeds, `T3` gets 2 and the release sequence stretching to `T1`, so `T3` synchronises-with `T1`.  If CAS fails, `T3` gets 1, which was written by `T1`, and so it  again synchronises-with `T1`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Boris The while loop in T2 is still necessary (if you want T3 to synchronize on value 2) because `compare_exchange_weak` can 'spuriously' fail (no apparent reason).
If the CAS fails, T3 will never observe 2 but still synchronize on 1 (T1->T3). If you use `if (load(relaxed)==1)` in T2 followed by a `compare_exchange_strong`, the while-loop isn't necessary.
But don't replace it with a plain store or you are back at square one.

Comment: I used a while-loop in my answer to make it possible that T1 synchronizes with T3 via T2. Of course, if the while-loop is missing and `atm` is not updated in T2, T1 will still synchronize with T3 (loading value 1) and it is as-if T2 had not done anything.

Comment: OK. The point I was unsure about was exactly that: in case of failure for any reason, neither loading nor the failure don’t break the release sequence. So, T3 synchronises either with T1 or T2, and either way it observes `x`. I think that’s clear now. Thank you again for a detailed explanation and for your patience: I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Boris np, I will add another (valid) implementation for T2 that uses an unconditional RMW

Comment: @Boris: In addition, you *could* just use `compare_exchange_strong` with no loop and no `if`, as the most direct equivalent to a single `if() store`, working just like that but with the if/store tied together as a single atomic RMW.  No spurious failure, only from actually seeing a `!=1` value with its load.  I was a bit surprised this answer chose to change the behaviour of Thread 2 that way (to always eventually store) without mentioning the single CAS attempt way, and was going to comment on it myself before seeing it had already come up in comments.